# In Julia, is it possible to pass values for evaluation in an Expr object without using global variables?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I'd like to be able to convert a string expression, e.g. "2.0*x*log(x)", to a function in Julia.  The usual way to do pass the value of "x" would be through global variables:

```
julia> func1 = parse("2.0*x*log(x)");
julia> x = 2.718281828459;
julia> eval(func1)/2.0
2.7182818284589545
```

However, I'd like to know if I can avoid using global variables.  I've tried the following two methods, but was not successful:

**Method 1**

```
julia> func2(x) = parse("2.0*x*log(x)");
julia> eval(func2(1.0))/2.0  # should return zero
2.7182818284589545
```

**Method 2**

```
julia> function new_func1(input_value)
           x = input_value
           eval(func1)
       end
new_func1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> new_func1(1.0)/2.0  # should return zero
2.7182818284589545
```

Comment: How about a string macro and an anonymous function.
`macro p_str(x)
    esc(parse(x))
end
func = x -> p"2.0*x*log(x)"
func(1.0)`

Comment: Or, suppose `funcstring="2.0*x*log(x)"`, then `eval(parse("func1(x) = $funcstring"))` will define `func1` with `func1(1.0)==0.0`

Comment: Thanks for the inputs--all of these work, as do the answers below.  I also realised it's possible to use "@generated" as well.

Answer (score 4):

How about doing this:

```
    ex = parse(string)
    @eval f(x) = $ex
```

When I plugged in your string and the number 1 it returned 0, 2 returned 2.772588 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

With `func2`, since you're not interpolating `x` within the function, the expression is being built with just symbol `x`. This is falling back to your global `x` you set when writing `func1`.

Try this:

```
julia> func2(x) = parse("2.0*$x*log($x)");

julia> eval(func2(1.0))
0.0
```

Or, alternatively,

```
julia> func2(x) = eval(parse("2.0*$x*log($x)"));

julia> func2(1.0)
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's also possible to use `@generated` to do this:

```
string = "2.0*x*log(x)"
@generated function my_func(x)
    return parse(string)
end
```

Sample output:

```
julia> println(my_func(1.0))
0.0

julia> println(my_func(exp(1.0))/2.0)
2.718281828459045

julia> println(my_func(0.5))
-0.6931471805599453
```

Thinking about this further, perhaps it would have been better to use the dot notation for multiplication:

```
string = "2.0.*x.*log(x)"
@generated function my_func(x)
    return parse(string)
end

julia> x = [1.0 0.5 exp(1.0)]
1x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.5  2.71828

julia> my_func(x)
1x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  -0.693147  5.43656
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite how to explain why this is a terrible idea to abuse `@generated` in this way, but your example here isn't doing what you seem to think it's doing.